# Postgresql installed through Brew does not start automatically

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

#### Story:

I installed postgresql using brew a while ago, but I haven't found a solution that it would start automatically on the startup. Do you have any solution?

#### Issue:

[image]

this is what I see when I try to connect to local database.

#### What I've tried:

This is `$ brew services list` output (single line)

`postgresql started root    /Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.postgresql.plist`

When installed, I followed instructions to start it now and after restart at login

#### Workaround:

Only workaround is to run this line

`pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start` which is quite inconvenient since I have to look it up in info page or assign to alias which I can't remember each time when I restart the computer.

Comment: Have you tried `brew services start postgresql`? That should automatically start the service after a restart.

Comment: @jdno yes, this is the command that added the row to the services list. Tried both with and without sudo.

Answer (score 3):

I realized most of these issues when my mac shutdown. To solve this, you may try this:

1. On your terminal run:  `postgres -D /usr/local/var/postgres`
2. Copy the PID returned and then run; `kill -9 <PID>`
3. Finally, run `brew services restart postgres`. That should do it for most of the cases